# Why there's a -1 byte in my FileInputStream?

Tags: java, io

When I use FileInputStream read a photo,and I found there's a '-1' in there.

Here's src.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        long stt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String file = "test/dlk.png", to = "test/test.png", output = file + ".bncchain.zip";
        byte[] password = "DLK IS SO HANDSOME".getBytes();
        String chainName = "dlk";

        try (BNCChuckChainOutputStream out = new BNCChuckChainOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output), chainName, password, 16384); FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            in.transferTo(out);
        }
        long edt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Encrypt TimeUsed:" + (edt - stt) + " ms");

        stt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (BNCChuckChainInputStream in = new BNCChuckChainInputStream(new FileInputStream(output), chainName, password); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(to)) {
            in.transferTo(fos);
        }
        edt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Decrypt TimeUsed:" + (edt - stt) + " ms");

    }
}
```

here's two files[raw-file](https://gitee.com/Bread_NiceCat/bread_nicecat/raw/master/dlk.png)&[wrong-file](https://gitee.com/Bread_NiceCat/bread_nicecat/raw/master/test.png)

I think 'BNCChuckChainOutputStream'and'BNCChuckChainInputStream' are both run correctly because I use the debug-tool calc. the md5 of input and output,they're equitive

[onWritePrtSc][3]

[3]: https://gitee.com/Bread_NiceCat/bread_nicecat/raw/master/ERRT(R(X9VVO%7BTNE%EF%BF%BD%5BMT0.png

Comment: What part of that code makes you think there's a `-1` in  there? Please provide an [mre] that clearly demonstrates your problem. Did you check what it means if [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) returns `-1`?

Comment: I expect that the problem is in code that you haven't shown us; e.g. the code where you are using `FileInputStream` to read the file.

Comment: Re your edit: your question shouldn't depend on external files and also those links are broken.

Comment: Define "there's a -1 in there". A `-1` could mean anything--`0xff` is `-1` as a twos-complement byte. That's a perfectly valid byte value; it's the interpretation of it that matters. If it's the result of a read *call* then `-1` means something different.

Comment: I tried to use debug-tools in Idea,but I have no idea to solve it,because for text,it works good

Comment: But binary data can include `-1`. It's still not clear what the *problem* is.

Comment: First do `"...".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or otherwise the default platform charset is used. For wide chars like `UTF-16LE` this would add bytes 0x00. As `byte` is signed, 0xFF or (byte)-1 happens. Hence never do `((byte) in.read())` as you then cannot detect end-of-file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Solved: (byte)255=>-1***

I debug the whole InputStream, and found it use **int** as data-saver.However,I used **byte[]** to save lots of data.